# Set parameters for sklearn pipeline transformer

Tags: scikit-learn

I have tried to set the parameters of an OneHotEncoder manually, but have received errors. What is the best solution for fitting the categories parameter which is a list of categories.

```
full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num", num_pipeline, num_attribs),
    ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), cat_attribs)
])

full_pipeline.set_params('cat', categories=one_hot_encodings)
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign parameters to your pipeline you have to use the syntax `<step>__<parameter>` where `<step>` stands for the name of your transform and `<parameter>` for the name of the transform's parameter.

In your case, this should work:

```
full_pipeline.set_params(cat__categories = one_hot_encodings)
```

or with a `dict` if you need to set multiple parameters:

```
full_pipeline.set_params({'cat__categories' : one_hot_encodings})
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Antoine Dubuis answer, if you want to use `set_params`with a `dict` use the following code:

```
full_pipeline.set_params(**{'cat__categories' : one_hot_encodings})
```